# How do mathematical Platonists think about formal systems?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I read that platonists believe there are abstract mathematical objects.

How do they think about formal systems? For example,

1. Do they discriminate the set of natural numbers N on ZF and that on ZFC?
2. Do they see the sets in a formal system as itself abstract mathematical objects, or as something gives expressions of the abstract objects?

Comment: See [Platonism in the Philosophy of Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/).

Comment: In a nutshell, for a platonist the (string of) symbol "one" refers to (it is the "name" of) an (abstract) object: **the** number **1**.

Comment: What do you mean with "the sets in a formal system as itself abstract mathematical objects" ?

Comment: To Mauro ALLEGRANZA. I mean that when it is said that 'We call something which satisfies the following axioms "sets" ', do platonists call these objects "sets" in their meaning?

Comment: I wonder whether it is a problem for platonists if a property P about sets is true in a axiomatic system T but false in another T'.

Comment: For a "pure" platonist : yes, *sets* exists and are the objects referred to by the (only) **true** theory of sets. Of course, the current "proliferation" of set theories (see [Alternative Axiomatic Set Theories](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/)) is a non trivial issue.

Comment: See : Penelope Maddy. [Realism in Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=5-8LVP00OJcC) (1992).

Answer (score 2):

I am currently reading Ian Hacking’s *Why is there  Philosophy of Mathematics at all*, and it is mostly about the contemporary dabate platonism/ nominalism, so I would recommend it as a good place to look for an answer to this question. A crude copy-paste is given below.

Hacking asserts that it is Paul Bernays who introduced the modern idea of 'platonism' and further he writes about the different brands of platonism, noting (p228):

> After Bernays had introduced the word 'platonism' to the philosophy of
>   mathematics, it should have been clear that one should not speak of platonism,
>   but about platonism restricted to some domain of objects, such as the
>   class of integers, or any Zermelo-Fraenkel set, or whatever. Perhaps even
>   something like the class of all ZF sets, in a van Neumann-Godel-Bernays
>   set theory.

So a good point to remember is that according to him

> Absolute platonism, asserting the existence of all definable mathematical
>   objects and relations, is untenable. What remain are relative platonisms.
>   The weakest interesting platonism described by Bernays asserts the existence
>   of a totality of whole numbers...a twenty-first-century platonist will say: positive integers are abstract objects. Kronecker said that God created them. So he thought they exist. That's a species of platonism - about numbers. He was a very modest platonist, but a platonist all the same.

Hacking comments:

> Such a thought seems never to have crossed Bernays' mind, for he thought of platonism in terms of totalities rather than 'abstract objects'.

So Bernays turns out to be a *restricted* platonist while

> In Bernays' vocabulary Boolos is a *cautious* platonist. He has no problem
>   about the totality of whole numbers, but he has many qualms about sets
>   whose existence is proven within Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory with the axiom
>   of choice.(229)

Perhaps there is something of an answer in this  heap of quotes